# Не отображается изображение в ImageButton

Tags: android, imageview

Почему-то в одном из моих фрагментов не отображаются картинки в ImageButton. Вот, собственно, код макета фрагмента:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.apbguides.apbreloadedguides.Guides.CreateGuideFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="14"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="top|left" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

А вот скриншот того, что получилось из этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, снизу видны пустые ImageButton, но картинок в них почему-то нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может картинки больших размеров?

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что у `ImageButton` есть атрибут `drawable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ImageButton`, как и `ImageView`, принимает изображение в атрибут `android:src`, а не `android:drawable`, как вы пытаетесь.

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: Чёрт, а ведь и верно) Смотрел на атрибуты и не видел)))

Comment: Спасибо, я утром уже сам понял:) просто не выспавшимся был)))